# Inconsistent word wrapping in legend of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, legend, pdf

I have been using word wrapping for my legends in ArcGIS 10.3.  I have had some success with this, but am getting errors in the way the labels are displayed.

Here is a pic of the settings:

[image]

The error is in the pdf output.  Sometimes the line will be wrapped, but the next line is missing.

In the following example, **Towns and Villages** (near top left) is cut off in the pdf output.

Here is the pdf output:

[image]

Here is the view from ArcMap:

[image]

I have searched online and have not been able to find any information about this error.  Has anyone had this error and discovered a fix?

Here is what I have had success with so far:

- Adding a space after the offending line makes it appear in the pdf output
- Workaround by adding multiple line descriptions and using those in the legend

I have tried adjusting the gaps in the layout settings.  This does not help.  I have also tried changing the label width to different values.  This also does not help.

---

I tried removing all other elements from the layout as Polygeo suggested.  Once I removed the other layers from the layout, the legend displayed properly in the pdf output, with the lines broken at the correct place and all text showing.  Then when I added all the layers back to the legend, it continued to display properly.  I need to test this further, but at the moment it appears that turning off all layers except the affected one (towns and villages in my example) and then turning the layers back on will fix the legend.

This is strange behavior.  The first time I opened the map today, I wrapped the labels in the legend and the label was cut off for towns and villages.  Then I turned off all the other layers in the map, and the label was no longer cut off.  I exported the map and the pdf output was fine.  Then I turned all the layers back on and the label was still displaying correctly in the map and pdf.  Then I restarted ArcMap expecting to get the wrapping error again, and I didn't get the error this time.  I'll test this again tomorrow.

Comment: Try to increase the gap values in the Gaps section. Maybe the wrapped label is hidden somewhere behind the second header.

Comment: @ahmadhanb - I have tried this and it does not help.  Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this a known bug??

Comment: Can you take everything out of your layout except the parts necessary to do that part of your legend and still see the problem?